# Invoke batch file with user input in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to invoke elasticsearch-keystore.bat file from Powershell. However, this batch asks user to enter password. How can I pass it from variable? There is an option to read setting value from stdin but I don't know how to make it work in Powershell.

I tried but with no success:

```
$password | Invoke-Expression "$elasticsearchFolder\bin\elasticsearch-keystore.bat add --stdin xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password -f"
```

Comment: That depends on what the batch file actually does. First and foremost you should [drop `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/), though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar once and pass some options after calling a bat.
I did this by saving the options to a txt and calling the bat like: bat.bat < options.txt

In your case, you can try:

```
$password>c:\temp\pass.txt
Invoke-Expression "$elasticsearchFolder\bin\elasticsearch-keystore.bat add --stdin xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password -f <c:\temp\pass.txt"
del c:\temp\pass.txt
```

But as Ansgar Wiechers said, depends on the bat and might not work with all of them.